# P4V(Perforce) filtering pending changelist with logical operators

Tags: perforce, p4v

With the latest P4V (Perforce) client, can we filter pending changelist with logical operators like AND/OR? So for example, filtering by "`Owner=me`", "`Client=myClientA AND myClientB`"? This will be convenient when unshelving from another client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(beside wondering what GUI you are using, I see "User:" and "Workspace:" at "Pending" tab)
P4V supports only **one entry** or **empty field** for filtering, so if you do not have too many clients clearing the "Workspace:" field should list you the candidates to unshelve.